# Time column update incrementally in SQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue with updating data.
In the time column has with same `sql` data, and i wanna increment the time values, like in the expected result below.

In the table.
Current data:

| date | time | pizza_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-05 | 10:22:00 | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:22:00 | 4 |
| 2023-01-02 | 10:22:00 | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:22:00 | 5 |
| 2023-03-01 | 10:22:00 | 2 |
| 2023-04-06 | 10:22:00 | 3 |
| 2023-04-09 | 10:22:00 | 1 |

Expected result:

| date | time | pizza_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-05 | 10:22:00 | 3 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:23:00 | 4 |
| 2023-01-02 | 10:24:00 | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 10:25:00 | 5 |
| 2023-03-01 | 10:26:00 | 2 |
| 2023-04-06 | 10:27:00 | 3 |
| 2023-04-09 | 10:28:00 | 1 |

How can i reach this on the more simplest way?
I currently using `postgre` for this, but the answer would be nice if it is more general.
Thank you your help, and your time.

Comment: as your dates have no order  it is difficult to get your result

Comment: There is no column that orders the data. How do you decide that this is the dataset that you want to update? Are there other records in this table that you don't want to affect? Why do you decide to start this at 10:22? You could use a `ROW_NUMBER` function to get an incrementing number and add that to the `time` column.

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely think through what and why you expect from your results, but once you clarify your ordering criteria, the method will likely remain similar. The [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function can give you 1-minute slots, [`row_number()over()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) can show you positions according to a certain order, that you can later join on:

```
create table pizza_times(id serial, date date, time time, pizza_id int);
insert into pizza_times (date,time,pizza_id) values
('2023-01-05',  '10:22:00', 3),
('2023-01-03',  '10:22:00', 4),
('2023-01-02',  '10:22:00', 1),
('2023-01-03',  '10:22:00', 5),
('2023-03-01',  '10:22:00', 2),
('2023-04-06',  '10:22:00', 3),
('2023-04-09',  '10:22:00', 1);

with cte as (
  select row_number()over() n, g
  from generate_series('today'::date+'10:22'::interval,
                       'tomorrow',
                       '1 minute')_(g) )
update pizza_times
set time=g::time
from cte 
where id=n
returning pizza_times.*;
```

| id | date | time | pizza_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 10:22:00 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 10:23:00 | 4 |
| 3 | 2023-01-02 | 10:24:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-01-03 | 10:25:00 | 5 |
| 5 | 2023-03-01 | 10:26:00 | 2 |
| 6 | 2023-04-06 | 10:27:00 | 3 |
| 7 | 2023-04-09 | 10:28:00 | 1 |

You can also make it happen on the fly using a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```
alter table pizza_times add column g_pizza_time time
generated always as ('10:21:00'::time+id*interval '1 minute') stored;

insert into pizza_times (date,time,pizza_id)
select 'today','00:00:00',6 returning *;
```

| id | date | time | pizza_id | g_pizza_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 2023-11-12 | 00:00:00 | 6 | 10:29:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xsoJk8pH)